# how to publish klocwork results on sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, klocwork

We are running both: Klocwork for C++ and SonarQube for Java and C# projects as a CI process using Jenkins. Since the SonarQube dashboard is much better, I would like to publish Klocwork results on the SonarQube.
Is it possible using some kind of Jenkins plugin? Any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SonarQube plugin for Klocwork available on this updated page: www.emenda.com/klocwork-sonarqube-plugin

You will need to complete the request form on the web page in order to obtain the resource.

Answer (score 2):

To publish Klockwork results in SonarQube you need not a Jenkins plugin but a SonarQube plugin. There [appears to be one](http://emenda.com/klocwork-sonar-plugin/) but I have no experience with it, and the screenshots on the site are quite old.

If you don't have any luck with it, another option would be to develop your own plugin. If you decide to go that route, you can post specific plugin development questions to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube).

Comment: I couldn't download this plugin. Do you supply it for free?

Comment: We don't supply it at all. Literally all I know about it is that there's a web site with rather old screenshots